# Selecting inner text of seq of html nodes

Tags: f#, html-agility-pack, f#-3.0, c#-to-f#

I currently have a C# web scrape using the HTML Agility pack with the end result being a List of string arrays representing the data from a row of tables. I am very new to F# and running into some issues understand how to parse this correctly. I'm also using this F# wrapper: https://fsnotebook.net/notebook/fssnip-kr/HtmlAgilityPack_FSharp

My C# code:

```cs
var body = document.DocumentNode.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == "body");
var table = body.Descendants("table").FirstOrDefault(t => t.Attributes.Contains("cellpadding") && t.Attributes["cellpadding"].Value == "1");
var rows =
    table.Descendants("tr")
         .Where(r => r.Attributes.Contains("bgcolor") && r.Attributes["bgcolor"].Value == "#ffffff");
List<string[]> athleteDatas =
    rows.Select(t => t.Descendants("td").Select(d => d.InnerText).ToArray()).ToList();
```

My F# code. So far I have a sequence of td elements, and I need to select the inner elements of each sequence as a string array and then put it back into a sequence/list.

```
 let resultsBody resultsPage =
    resultsPage
    |> createDoc
    |> descendants "table"
    |> Seq.filter (hasAttr "cellpadding" "1")
    |> Seq.head
    |> descendants "tr"
    |> Seq.filter (hasAttr "bgcolor" "#ffffff")
    |> Seq.map(descendants "td")
    |> Seq.toArray
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the missing part is contained within a `.Select(...)` in the original code, so you need to modify your `map` similarly:

```
|> Seq.map (descendants "td" >> Seq.map innerText >> Array.ofSeq)
```

Or if you have some difficulty with point-free:

```
|> Seq.map (fun line ->
    line
    |> descendants "td"
    |> Seq.map innerText
    |> Array.ofSeq)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify this by using XPath. This returns a `seq<string>`. If you want a list or array, pipe the last line to `Seq.toList`/`Seq.toArray`.

```
open HtmlAgilityPack

let html = """
<html>
    <body>
        <table cellpadding="1">
            <tbody>
                <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    <td>
                        Some text.
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>"
"""

let doc = HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml(html)
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body/table[@cellpadding='1']//tr[@bgcolor='#ffffff']/td")
|> Seq.map (fun n -> n.InnerText)
```

Comment: Thank you. This actually makes much more sense, however I found a bug after posting this where I'd need to do where the bgcolor is not a specific color. I'm not familiar enough with XPath to do that.

Comment: Just change `@bgcolor=<value>` to `@bgcolor!=<value>`. The [XPath examples on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx) are a good intro.